# Why do we put & in copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I am a c++ newbie and i want to know that why do we need to put & in the copy constructor in c++ class.I understand that using ampersand provides the reference of the object to be copied and a new copy of the object is not created.But why am i not allowed to copy the object (ignoring the memory usage point)?

Comment: "But why am i not allowed to copy the object" - what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Think about it: in order to pass an object to a copy constructor, a copy of it would need to be made, using - what else - a copy constructor. But in order to call that one, a copy of the object would need to be made, using a copy constructor. But...

Comment: @ AndreyT sorry for the confusion.Actually i meant that why was i not allowed to pass the object by value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't specify call by reference, you have call by value: the compiler will generate a call to the copy constructor to pass the argument.  If the copy constructor took its parameter by value, you'd end up with an endless recursion.

Answer (score 0):

if we do like this, ClassA a = b (which is already constructed ClassA),
and the implementation of Copy Constructor as,

ClassA::ClassA(ClassA a)
{
   // put your code to copy
}

Then, for this call, copy constructor will be called infinite times for every ClassA a = b.